# JQuery Multiple selectors :first and :contains text()

Tags: jquery

```
var text = $('span:first:contains("From:")').siblings(span).text()
```

I want to select only the text whose sibling is the first span containing the text 'From:'. There is a second "From:" on the page and so the above query without ':first' works without error but it returns both texts. I just want the text related to the first instance of 'From:'. In xpath I think I could just add a [0] on the end. But I don't know how to 'nest' the :first selector (pseudo selector?). I'm new at jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should share your HTML structure so we have better understanding of what you are trying to do.

From your explanation I understand you are trying to do this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    var text = $('span:contains("From:"):first').siblings('span').text();
    
  $('.display').text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Testing From: text 1 </span>
  <span>Sibling of text 1</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Testing From: text 2 </span>
  <span>Sibling of text 2</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Testing From: text 3 </span>
  <span>Sibling of text 3</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="display"></div>
```

it is almost the same as your code, but I have switched the places of the ":first" selector and the ":contains". But maybe I did not understand what you are explaining.

Comment: Thanks - I did try putting the :first after the :contains but it wasn't working. I managed to get it to work using a filter

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using a filter:

```
var text = $('span:contains("From:")').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).first().siblings('span').text();
```

Comment: That filter doesn't make sense and is doing nothing relevant. Remove it and you get `$('span:contains("From:")').first().siblings('span').text()` which does same thing

Comment: Yeah you're right, that does work. I don't know jquery, I just played around and found that filter worked but your answer makes a lot more sense